# Работа с методом push

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт:

```js
var quene = [5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2];
var cur_par = [5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3];
var current_parrent, path = [], parent_path = [];

while (quene != '') {
  cur_top = quene.shift();
  current_parrent = cur_par.shift();

  if (path == '') {
    path[path.length] = [cur_top];
    parent_path[cur_top] = [path.length - 1];
  } else {
    path.push(path[parent_path[current_parrent]]); //этот push добавляет строки копируя определенную предыдущую строку
    this_top = cur_top;
    path[path.length - 1].push(this_top); //этот добавляет значения в  строки
    parent_path[cur_top] = [path.length - 1];
  }
}

console.log(path);
```

Вывод `console.log(path);` должен быть обязательно числовым и таким:

```
[[5], [5, 4], [5, 3], [5, 4, 1], [5, 3, 1], [5, 3, 2]]
```

Каким образом вообще я здесь получаю 6 массивов из 6-ти элементов, при чем просто смешав все точки воедино?

```
[Array[6], Array[6], Array[6], Array[6], Array[6], Array[6]]
```

Комментарии объясняют мой ход мыслей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема в том, что сохраняется ссылка на один и тот же массив, поэтому при добавлении в него элементов изменения были видны везде.

Для исправления можно воспользоваться методами [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) либо [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Кроме того, для проверки наличия элементов в массиве лучше использовать свойство `length`.

```js
var quene = [5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2];
var cur_par = [5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3];
var current_parrent, path = [],
  parent_path = [];

while (quene.length > 0) {
  cur_top = quene.shift();
  current_parrent = cur_par.shift();
  if (path.length == 0) {
    path[path.length] = [cur_top];
    parent_path[cur_top] = [path.length - 1];
  } else {
    path.push([].concat(path[parent_path[current_parrent]])); //этот push добавляет строки копируя определенную предыдущую строку
    this_top = cur_top;
    path[path.length - 1].push(this_top); //этот добавляет значения в  строки
    parent_path[cur_top] = [path.length - 1];
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(path));
```

Comment: Вы гений. Но я никак не пойму. Каким именно образом я удерживал там ссылку на один и тот же элемент?

Comment: @Levelleor, в `path` у тебя хранятся массивы. в строке `path.push([].concat(path[parent_path[current_parrent]]))` ты получаешь ссылку на массив `path[parent_path[current_parrent]])` и сохраняешь ее же в `path` в итоге у тебя много ссылок и один массив