# Изменение элементов в массиве через другую переменную

Tags: javascript, массивы, переменные

Почему так происходит?

```
var q = [1, 2, 3];
var w = q;
q[0] = 0;

console.log(w) // [0, 2, 3]
```

Т.е. массив не копируется а просто создаётся ссылка на тот же массив. Почему?

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса: [Работа с методом push](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578943/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-push/578948#578948)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что так работают практически все языки. Гораздо дешевле при копировании объектов скопировать ссылку (размером в 4 или в 8 байт), чем копировать каждый объект массива, а у каждого объекта в свою очередь копировать все его свойства, которые тоже могут быть объектами или массивами. Это заняло бы очень много времени.

Comment: Т. е. вопрос в оптимизации. Вообще, давно работаю с js, но почему-то до этого не натыкался на такое поведение

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz видимо, мало работаете. Потому что это поведение по умолчанию. Оно не распространяется на "простые типы", такие, как строки, числа и логические значения, которые копируются по значению.

Answer (score 3):

Объекты в JS (к которым относятся и массивы) копируются в переменную "по ссылке". Чтобы избежать этого, необходимо произвести клонирование массива (у нового массива будет новая внутренняя ссылка). 
Для этого можно использовать методы:

```
var w = q.slice();
```

Или более современный метод ES6

```
var w = [...q];
```

Comment: Спасибо, полезно

Answer (score 3):

Что бы создать копию, сделай так:

```
var q = [1, 2, 3];
var w = q.slice();
```